# Angular 5: clicked button that triggers a dialog becomes highlighted after the dialog is closed

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-material-5

I noticed that button gets classes cdk-focused and cdk-program-focused added *after* the dialog it triggered is closed. If I click anywhere effect disappears.

**app.component.html** [fragment]

```
<mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
  <span matTooltip="Delete" matTooltipPosition="right">
    <button mat-icon-button color="warn" (click)="openDeleteAssociationDialog()">
      <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
    </button>
  </span>
</mat-cell>
```

[image: Illustration]

Comment: this is on purpose and a accessibility feature: https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/5129

Comment: is there a way to alter this feature behavior? as it makes no sense in this case

Comment: @Paul had you get rid of this styling? i want to get rid of from such styling.

Comment: @yuzhou provided the solution below

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Add to your button in HTML some id. In my case it's **#changeButton**:

```html
<button #changeButton mat-icon-button (click)="changeItem(element)" disableRipple>
    <mat-icon>edit</mat-icon>
</button>
```

2. Import ViewChild and ElementRef in the .ts file:

```typescript
{ ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
```

3. Declare a new variable in the .ts file:

```js
@ViewChild('changeButton') private changeButton: ElementRef;
```

4. Subscribe to your dialog's **afterClose()** event and remove the **cdk-program-focused** css class:

```js
dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
    this.changeButton['_elementRef'].nativeElement
        .classList.remove('cdk-program-focused');
}
```

Answer (score 14):

Here the better solution is using the configuration property `restoreFocus: false`

```
matDialog.open(<your-component>, {
    restoreFocus: false
});
```

In this case, when you close matDialog using matDialogRef.close(), the focus will not apply to that delete button/icon.

Refer: https://github.com/angular/components/issues/8420 - it has other alternative solutions including `restoreFocus: false`.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the real problem stay in button structure, 'material' build various sub components and last one is a 'div' with css class 'mat-button-focus-overlay':

My solution is simply, in 'style.css' file, add or sobrescribe the 'mat-button-focus-overlay'

```
.mat-button-focus-overlay { background-color: transparent!important; }
```

Answer (score 1):

This style fixed for me:

```
.mat-button, .mat-flat-button, .mat-stroked-button
{   
    &.cdk-program-focused .mat-button-focus-overlay
    {
        opacity: 0 !important;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use it like this

```
        .mat-icon-button,
        a.mat-button {
            &.cdk-focused,
            &.cdk-program-focused {
                background-color: transparent;
    
                .mat-button-focus-overlay {
                    display: none;
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply over ride the css in the mat-dialog consuming file

```
.mat-button-focus-overlay { 
  background-color: transparent!important;
 }
```

In your case, add this css in `mat-cell` component's css file.

Answer (score 0):

Based off @yuzhou, I found that some buttons still retain some form of focus. Instead of removing the classes, I call blur on the element, this solves my problem.

```js
dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
    this.changeButton['_elementRef'].nativeElement.blur(); 
}
```